# StructureMap: How to get a named instance within a constructor

Tags: c#, delegates, inversion-of-control, structuremap, func

**Main:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new CompositionRoot();

        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        var consumer = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Consumer>();
        consumer.Parse();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Parsers:**

```
public interface IFilePaser
{
    void Parse(string line);
}

public class ITMFileParser : IFilePaser
{
    public void Parse(string line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ITM");
    }
}

public class SEQFilePaser : IFilePaser
{
    public void Parse(string line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SEQ");
    }
}
```

**CompositionRoot:**

```
public class CompositionRoot
{
    public CompositionRoot()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x=>x.Scan(scan =>
                                               {
                                                   scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                                                   scan.AddAllTypesOf<IFilePaser>().NameBy(NameBy);
                                               }));

        Consumer.Factory = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IFilePaser>;
    }



    private static string NameBy(Type type)
    {
        return type.Name.Replace("FileParser", "");
    }
}
```

**Consumer:**

```
public class Consumer
{
    public static Func<string, IFilePaser> Factory = name => { throw new NotImplementedException(""); };

    public void Parse()
    {
        Factory("ITM").Parse("");
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to use the following refactored **Consumer**?

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly Func<string, IFilePaser> _filePaser;

    public Consumer(Func<string, IFilePaser> filePaser)
    {
        _filePaser = filePaser;
    }

    public void Parse()
    {
        _filePaser("ITM").Parse("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StructureMaps Func<T>` trick isn't implemented for named instances. You need to register this explicitly:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => {
   x.Scan(scan => {
      scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
      scan.AddAllTypesOf<IFileParser>().NameBy(NameBy);
   });

   x.For<Func<string, IFileParser>>().Use(ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IFileParser>); 
});
```